# Как при разных условиях в JavaScript выводить разный HTML код?

Tags: javascript

К примеру есть такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cur_width = $(window).width();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 720 && cur_width > 720){
        //reload
        location.reload();
    }
    else if($(window).width() > 720 && cur_width <= 720){
        //reload
        location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Как в этом коде вместо перезагрузки выводить html?

Comment: вернее я хочу код разместить в tpl на smarty. в одном условие мне нужна загрузка такая: {block name='product_images_modal'}{include file='catalog/1.tpl'}{/block}, в другом: {block name='product_images_modal'}{include file='catalog/2.tpl'}{/block}

Answer (score 0):

```
var cur_width = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 720 && cur_width > 720){
        document.body.innerHTML = 'SomeData';
    }
    else if($(window).width() > 720 && cur_width <= 720){
        document.body.innerHTML = 'SomeOtherData';
    }
});
```

Comment: что-то не работает.

Comment: А чуть более конкретное поведение? просто не работает и нет никаких ошибок?)

Comment: Ничего вообще. Я не уточнил одну деталь, скрипт размещается в *.tpl на smarty, в этой теме я сделал уточнение:

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-tpl-%D0%BD%D0%B0-smarty-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B