# Как при разных условиях в JavaScript выводить в tpl на smarty выводить два разных шаблона?

Tags: javascript, smarty

К примеру есть такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cur_width = $(window).width();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 720 && cur_width > 720){
        //reload
        location.reload();
    }
    else if($(window).width() > 720 && cur_width <= 720){
        //reload
        location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Я хочу разместить в tpl на smarty код. В котором: в одном условие мне нужна загрузка такая: {block name='product_images_modal'}{include file='catalog/1.tpl'}{/block}, в другом: {block name='product_images_modal'}{include file='catalog/2.tpl'}{/block}

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [Ajax](https://habr.com/ru/post/14246/) для динамической загрузки контента. 
Ваш JS скрпит работает на стороне клиента, а шаблон формируется на стороне сервера.
Так что по сути то что вы хотите сделать можно реализовать лишь подгружая либо сразу оба шаблона(что не есть хорошо) либо подгружать второй шаблон с помощю указаной технологии при наступлении нужных событий.

p.s. если вы используете фреймворк jQuery вы можете сильно упростить себе жизнь его возможностями по формированию запросов: [$.Get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) [$.Post](http://api.jquery.com/JQuery.post/) [$.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/JQuery.ajax/)

P.s.s.
Дополняю примером использования с jQuery:
Smarty

```
{if $ParamPG eq 'm1'}
  {include file='catalog/1.tpl'}
{elseif $ParamPG eq 'm2'}
  {include file='catalog/2.tpl'}
{/if}
```

PHP

```
$ParamPG  = (isset($_GET['ParamPG ']) ? $_GET['ParamPG '] : 'm1' );
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cur_width = $(window).width();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 720 && cur_width > 720){
        $.get( "{!URL!}?ParamPG=m1", function( data ) {document.body.innerHTML= data})
    }
    else if($(window).width() > 720 && cur_width <= 720){
        $.get( "{!URL!}?ParamPG=m2", function( data ) {document.body.innerHTML= data})
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: я слабо разбираюсь в фрейворках. мне бы понять, как при разных условиях загружать разные шаблоны. в коде есть перезагрузка страницы, не Ajax, но тоже достойный вариант. Я хочу сделать сильно разные версии адаптива.

Comment: Ну а вариантов у вас с использованием разных серверных шаблонов не много, либо Ajax либо перезагрузка страницы. Без фреймворков - смотрите первую ссылку.

Comment: можете подсказать как шаблон в условие вписать?

Comment: могу, это делается на стороне php или smarty, а с JS нужно передавать это в виде параметра запроса. для простоты понимания. Сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: Да... непросто оказывается. Я думал делается легче.

Comment: `$("#div").load("getSomeHtml.php", { size: $(window).width() })` на стороне js

Comment: далее сравнить `$_POST['size']` в пхп, и в зависимости от этого отрендерить нужный шаблон `$smarty->render('my-template.tpl')`

Comment: но прям такой обработчик resize будет постоянно грузить блоки, а вам по сути надо загрузить только когда это реально надо при переходе границы. а не при каждом изменении на 1 пиксель.

Comment: @teran Лучше бы это ответом, т.к. хоть это по сути и одно и тоже с тем что я говорил автору - но подход иной.

Comment: Меня не совсем вы поняли. Основное решение есть уже в коде выше. Но, нужно tpl вывести в определенном тэге, или между тэгами. Я попробую позже дополнить вопрос, и объяснить лаконичнее, чтобы кто-нибудь из вас или другой юзер написал ответ для утверждения.

Comment: `$('какойто_тэг').html('Какойто текст который нужно поместить в элемент <какойто_тэг></какойто_тэг>')`